# How to have SQLite/PDO->query() only return named fields?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

If I get records from my SQLite database's master table like this:

```
$database = new PDO('sqlite:test.sqlite');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master";
$records = $database-> query($sql);
```

then it gives me double the amount of fields in each record, both indexed and associative:

```
type:[table]
0:[table]
name:[site_comments]
1:[site_comments]
tbl_name:[site_comments]
2:[site_comments]
rootpage:[3]
3:[3]
sql:[CREATE•TABLE•site_comments(author•varchar(50),•comment•varchar(255))]
4:[CREATE•TABLE•site_comments(author•varchar(50),•comment•varchar(255))]
```

I remember using the PDO object many years ago and there were `fetchAll()` et al. methods which was how you determined if you wanted both associative or indexed fields, or one or the other, etc. But this seems to be a new/different version of PDO (PHP installed with the newest version of XAMPP):

[image]

**How do I tell the PDO object that I want it to give me only the named arrays, e.g. "type" and "name", but not 0 and 1?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`PDO::query`](http://php.net/PDO.query) returns a [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/PDOStatement). Use [`PDOStatement::setFetchMode`](http://php.net/PDOStatement.setFetchMode) to set the default fetch mode, or pass the mode when calling [`fetch`](http://php.net/PDOStatement.fetch) on the result. Note you set the fetch mode on the result after running `PDO::query`, not on the PDO object before running the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the PDO class itself so every time you use the query() method, it setFetchMode's how you want:

```
class PDO_Ex extends PDO {

    function query($query){

        $statement = parent::query($query);
        $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $statement;
    }

}
```